# Get Salesforce Object List

Tags: python, salesforce

I'm trying to pull a list of all the Salesforce Objects (tables names) from Salesforce.  In the examples I see of people getting the Object data, the name of the Object is already known.  I want to see the entire list of Objects prior to that.  Is this possible?  I am using simple_salesforce.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it

```
for x in sf.describe()["sobjects"]:
    print(x["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()` to get descriptions of each object, which are of type `Schema.SObjectType`. Then you can call the `.getDescribe()` method to get the object description, then call the `.getName()` method on the object description to get the object name:

```
for(Schema.SObjectType objectType : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
    String name = objectType.getDescribe().getName();
    System.debug('Object name is==>' +name);
}
```

Comment: Hi,Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please mark the code segments accordingly as code blocks. 
Also please add some 1-2 lines of descriptions if possible so that the OP can understand. Thanks